# How to find cells with a similar name in the column and summarize them with Python, and Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge CVS file with data in it and I need to summarize cells by columns in very specific way.

My DataFrame is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Brazil','Brazil','Brazil','Brazil','Brazil','Brazil','Chile'], 'city': ['Salvador','Salvador','Teresina','Teresina','Teresina','','Iquique'], 'name':['Gabriela','Gabriela','Maria','Fernanda','Carla','Solange','Isabel'], 'salary':[10.11,20.0,13.5,9.4,1.2,4.0,2.1], 'bonus':[3.3,4.2,7.1,0.2,5.1,2.0,1.1]})
```

```
   country      city      name  salary  bonus
0  Brazil  Salvador  Gabriela   10.11    3.3
1  Brazil  Salvador  Gabriela   20.00    4.2
2  Brazil  Teresina     Maria   13.50    7.1
3  Brazil  Teresina  Fernanda    9.40    0.2
4  Brazil  Teresina     Carla    1.20    5.1
5  Brazil             Solange    4.00    2.0
6   Chile   Iquique    Isabel    2.10    1.1
```

I need to find rows with similar name in cells by column **name** and summarize next after them by column **salary** and by column **bonus**.

The output table must be looking like that:

```
   country      city  salary  bonus
0  Brazil  Salvador   30.11    7.5
1  Brazil  Teresina   24.10   12.4
2  Brazil              4.00    2.0
3   Chile   Iquique    2.10    1.11
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to group by country and city, and then summing all the rest:

```py
new_df = df.groupby(['country','city']).agg({'salary': 'sum', 'bonus': 'sum'})
```

This will return a dataframe as you wish.

The `groupby` is using to match countries and cities identical rows together, and the `agg` tells what function to apply - summing in your case

Answer (score 0):

Just a `groupby` on city and country should do it:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['city', 'country'], as_index=False).sum()
print(df)

       city country  salary  bonus
0            Brazil    4.00    2.0
1   Iquique   Chile    2.10    1.1
2  Salvador  Brazil   30.11    7.5
3  Teresina  Brazil   24.10   12.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby (on `['country','city']`) and specify which columns you want to calculate the sum on (`['salary', 'bonus']`) like this:

```
df.groupby(['country','city'], as_index=False)['salary', 'bonus'].sum()

  country      city  salary  bonus
0  Brazil              4.00    2.0
1  Brazil  Salvador   30.11    7.5
2  Brazil  Teresina   24.10   12.4
3   Chile   Iquique    2.10    1.1
```